# Fermentis S04 vs.US05

Tags: fermentation, yeast, wyeast

I am trying dried yeast for the first time. I did up 100 litres of English IPA yesterday and I pitched 2xS04 into 50 litres and 2xUSO5 into 50 litres.

Anybody want to hazard a guess at the fermentation times? I am fermenting at about 18 degress C.

Is 04 faster than 05?

Are both faster than liquid Wyeast?

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious... why would you care about speed? When I test with different ingredients in an otherwise same batch, I'd try to see what the difference in taste is.

Comment: Tasting I will be doing for sure, just interested in seeing if there is a notable time difference from using Wyeast, which I wait a full 14 days for.

Answer (score 2):

Fermentation time will depend on a lot of factors...if you want to compare to Wyeast, you need to specify which strain.  05 and 1056 ferment in about the same amount of time. but 05 often takes longer to drop clear.  I think 05 -may- ferment a bit faster than 04, but no guarantees.  The difference in flavor between 04 and 05 is dramatic.

Comment: Nice one. Cheers. I use British Ale and Whitbread mostly, with the odd 1203 Burton IPA thrown in there..... so I figured I will try 05 in my IPA and 04 in my (dark) Pale Ale, but thought it best to try both on my IPA first so I can see the taste difference.

Answer (score 1):

The ferm times were about the same. What was different was the taste. An UNBELIEVABLE difference. It really doesn't taste like the same beer. You really wouldn't know it was the same beer in fact. I preferred the 04, but many did prefer the 05. Anyway, I use the brews now to show folks the difference yeast makes as most don't really consider it as important it seems. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Based on past experience they both ferment to FG in about the same time. US05 is more aggressive and will go much drier, and S-04 will give you more British Ale esters.

I have a couple of ales I make with both. I add 2/3 S-04 and 1/3 US-05, this gives me the lovely fruity esters of S-04, but finishes nice and dry from the US-05 chewing through all the extra sugars.

Comment: Nice plan. I like it. I may well give that a go! Cheers!